# How to convince ocaml that two functor instantiations are equal

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have a number of modules that are all parameterized with one module type, and also have dependencies between each other:

```
module type AT = sig  
end

module B(A: AT) = struct
  module Hash = struct
    type t = int
    let equal b1 b2 = b1 = b2
    let hash b = b
  end
end

module C(A: AT) = struct
  module B = B(A)
  module Hashtbl = Hashtbl.Make(B.Hash)

  let make () = Hashtbl.create 16
end

module D(A: AT) = struct
  module B = B(A)
  module Hashtbl = Hashtbl.Make(B.Hash)

  let use ht =
    Hashtbl.clear ht
end

module E(A: AT) = struct
  module C = C(A)
  module D = D(A)

  let f () =
    D.use (C.make ())
end
```

Here, everything is parameterized with `AT`. Then, `C` and `D` are independent, and `E` depends on `C` and `D`. This code does not compile, since the compiler is not convinced that inside `E`, `C.Hashtbl` and `D.Hashtbl` are the same module:

```
File "xxxx.ml", line xx, characters xx-xx:
Error: This expression has type 'a C.Hashtbl.t = 'a Hashtbl.Make(C.B.Hash).t
       but an expression was expected of type
         'b D.Hashtbl.t = 'b Hashtbl.Make(D.B.Hash).t
```

Is there a quick way to convince ocaml that the two hashset modules are the same?

Answer (score 5):

The typechecker is right that the two `Hashtbl` modules are not the same and should not be mixed together: consider for instance a slightly modified `B` module:

```
module B(A: AT) = struct
  module Hash = struct
    let y = Random.int 10
    type t = int
    let equal b1 b2 = b1 = b2
    let hash b = b + y
  end
end
```

Then the two instances `C.B` and `D.B` of the functor application `F(A)` do not share the same salt. Consequently, mixing hash tables derived from `C.B.Hash` and `D.B.Hash` would be an error that leads to a completely erratic behavior.

Comment: After reading a bit more, I think, you are wrong. Ocaml functors are supposed to be applicative, and applications of the functor to the same module should be considered the same by the typechecker, even if the modules capture different values due to side effects. I've created a separate question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48895723/302086