# What are the rules for equality of types and modules in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I cannot wrap my head around equality of modules in OCaml. Functors are supposed to be applicative (that's what the Internet claims), but this seems to fail sometimes, and I cannot quite see the general rule behind it.

That's my example code:

```
module type PT = sig end
module P = struct end

let () =
  Random.self_init ()

module OrigHashtbl = Hashtbl
module Hashtbl = struct
  module Make(Hash: OrigHashtbl.HashedType) = struct
    let random = Random.int 1000000

    type 'a t = { t_list: (Hash.t * 'a) list }

    let create _ =
      Format.printf "Random %d@." random;
      { t_list = [] }          

    let mem ht v =
      Format.printf "Random %d@." random;
      List.mem_assoc v ht.t_list          
  end
end

module Hash = struct
  type t = int
  let equal x1 x2 = x1 = x2
  let hash x = x
end

module Wrap(P: PT) = struct
  module H = Hashtbl.Make(Hash)
end

module Wrap1 = Wrap(P)
module Wrap2 = Wrap(P)
module H1 = Wrap1.H
module H2 = Wrap2.H

let () =
  let ht = H1.create 16 in
  Format.printf "%b@." (H2.mem ht 0)
```

Code at ideone: https://ideone.com/5C8Muk

What I do here is I create a dummy implementation of some functions from `Hashtbl` module and wrap it in the functor `Wrap` which I 'call' twice, creating `H1` and `H2` which can be used interchangeably despite them being different modules that capture different value of `random`:

```
$ ./test.byte 
Random 501586
Random 681009
false
```

This is expected, because, as the Internet claims, OCaml functors are applicative.

But then I try to move the `Hash` module inside `Wrap` and the program stops compiling.

```
module Wrap(P: PT) = struct
  module Hash = struct
    type t = int
    let equal x1 x2 = x1 = x2
    let hash x = x
  end

  module H = Hashtbl.Make(Hash)
end
```

Code at Ideone: https://ideone.com/Gjxc32

```
$ ocamlbuild test.byte
+ /home/XXX/.opam/4.04.0/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -o test.cmo test.ml
File "test.ml", line 41, characters 35-37:
Error: This expression has type 'a H1.t = 'a Hashtbl.Make(Wrap1.Hash).t
       but an expression was expected of type
         'b H2.t = 'b Hashtbl.Make(Wrap2.Hash).t
```

Why is that? I'd expect that if `Wrap1` and `Wrap2` are the same module (because functors should be applicative, right?) then `Wrap1.Hash` and `Wrap2.Hash` are also the same. What's the general rule behind comparing modules?

Note: This is a continuation of another question [How to convince ocaml that two functor instantiations are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48693701/302086). There the only answer I got was along the lines of "OCaml functors are generative" which is false (at least sometimes).

**Edit**

Perhaps, I was wrong asking about module equality. What I'm actually interested in is type equality. Why in some cases `Wrap1.H.t` equals `Wrap2.H.t` and in some cases - not.

**Answer**

After a discussion with @Drup, things became more clear for me. Applicativeness means the following: if `A = B`, then `F(A) =/= F(B)`, but `F(A).t = F(B).t`. For the modules defined inside `F(A)` and `F(B)`, things depend on how these modules are defined. In my example, whether or not `Wrap1.H.t = Wrap2.H.t` depends on the definition of `H`. In the variant that compiles, `Wrap1.H.t = Hashtbl(Hash).t = Wrap2.H.t`. In the variant that does not compile, `Wrap1.H.t = Hashtbl(Wrap1.Hash).t` and `Wrap2.H.t = Hashtbl(Wrap2.Hash).t`, and they are distinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Applicative functors" means that `A = B` implies `F(A).t = F(B).t`. It *doesn't* implies that `F(A).M = F(B).M`. It's about types, not modules.

One fundamental difference between creation of types and creation of modules is that creating types is side-effect free (hence can be treated with an applicative behavior). Creating a module is not side effect free, hence you can't consider two different fresh modules as being the same.
octachron gave a pretty good example in the last answer.

If you want to keep the equality while still having local modules, you can use module aliases. If you do this instead:

```
module Hash0 = struct
  type t = int
  let equal x1 x2 = x1 = x2
  let hash x = x
end
module Wrap(P: PT) = struct
  module Hash = Hash0 (* the type of this module is "= Hash0" *)
  module H = Hashtbl.Make(Hash)
end
```

Then the program is accepted.

Note that, even in your failing version, `Wrap1.Hash.t = Wrap2.Hash.t` holds (regardless of its definition), even if the modules are not equals.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand here is if `F(A).t = F(B).t` then why in some cases `F(A).M.t = F(B).M.t` and in some cases - not. I guess, I was wrong asking about "module equality", because type equality is what I'm interested here.

Comment: In order to have `Wrap1.H.t = Wrap2.H.t`, applicativeness dictate that you should have `Wrap1.Hash = Wrap2.Hash`. However, as I showed above, that is not the case if `Hash` is declared inside the functor, even if said functor is applicative.

Comment: Ok, I see so whether or not `Wrap1.H.t = Wrap2.H.t` depends on the definition of `H`. In the variant that compiles, `Wrap1.H.t = Hashtbl(Hash).t = Wrap2.H.t`. In the variant that does not compile, `Wrap1.H.t = Hashtbl(Wrap1.Hash).t` and `Wrap2.H.t = Hashtbl(Wrap2.Hash).t`, and they are distinct. I'll mark your answer as accepted and add the result of this discussion to the end of the question. Thanks.